# Hibernate/JPA - Insert a field only if exists in table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I am looking for an answer if it is possible or not in hibernate. What I am trying to achieve is that if a field exists in a particular table then only it should insert it. Else just ignore the field in the @Entity class.
I want this as a new field is going to introduce in one of the table we are using and there are many dependent components which right now insert the data into that table. I don't want a big bang release. Want something like it doesn't impact the older version as well as when the upgrade happens and a new column introduced then also it should work.

For example -

```
 @Entity
    @Table(name = "EMPLOYEE_RECORDS")
    public class Employee
    {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "employee_id")
        private Integer employeeId;

        @Column(name = "employee_name")
        private String employeeName;

        @Column(name="address")
        private String address;
}
```

What if I only want to insert address field into DB only when column(address) exists in the table **EMPLOYEE_RECORDS**. Please forgive me if this is something obvious, as I am not very proficient in Hibernate.

Also let me explain what have I thought of (But not sure if it will also work) - 
1. Create 2 different @Entity classes. Try to insert and if the insertion failed then at runtime switch the @Entity and use without address.
2. Check if field exist in the table by simple query if it fails use @Entity without address else use without address.

Comment: Fields which are **not** annotated with `@Transient` **must** be present in the table

Comment: So its also not possible to keep 2 @Entity classes one of which has a field which is not in the table, right?

Comment: you can have less entity fields than table column but you can not just use it like  @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) like Json serialize .

Comment: @NIVESHSENGAR So you can not be sure of the tables you will use??

Comment: I am sure but I was thinking to make it future proof and backward compatible. So the change in DB doesn't affect the application. Now I am having a feeling, the application needs to be changed whenever there is a addition of this new field in DB

Comment: Only if you want to fill that field as well. You might only need minor changes to support that field, but maybe those are larger changes

Answer (score -1):

I'm very confused about the scenario - It seems like there were deeper issues regarding decoupling of components in your system.

Nevertheless, you can add the column in the database, but you don't need to declare the field in the hibernate entity. On the other hand there is no way you can have an optional field in an hibernate entity. Either a field is mapped or it is not mapped.